# set valid CXF path in WebServices plugin settings

Tags: java, spring, intellij-idea, soap, cxf

While trying to generate Java Code from WSDL file using CXF I am getting following error on UI

> set valid CXF path in WebServices plugin settings

Attached is a screenshot of same:-

[image]

Answer (score 2):

you can find config in Preferences->Tools->WebServices->CXF

then download http://apache.forsale.plus/cxf/3.2.4/apache-cxf-3.2.4.zip
finish config.

Comment: you can download  wsdl2java  then run cmd like  ./bin/wsdl2java -p client4_cxf -d /Users/****/project/test/src/main/java https://test-gcc.globalsign.com/kb/ws/v1/GASService\?wsdl

Answer (score 1):

Error: ***set valid CXF path in web services plugin settings***

---

You have to download and config *Apache CXF* engine in your *IntelliJ IDE*.

At first download **binary distribution** of *Apache CXF* from this link:
https://cxf.apache.org/download.html

Then extract it somewhere in your computer

and in IntelliJ press ***Ctrl+Alt+S*** and in path

> Settings -> Tools -> Web Services

and in ***External engines*** section select appropriate extracted folder of downloaded *Apache CXF*:

[image]